# BackgroundColor property changes on Android but not on iOS

Tags: android, ios, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

The code works perfectly on **Android**, I tested it on two devices, an emulator and my phone but when I run the code on an **iPhone** emulator or phone the `BackgroundColor` property never sets and it's just transparent.

I have a `SfBorder` which has its `BackgroundColorProperty` bound to a `Converter`. The converter sends back a color based on a percentage value.

This is where the `SfBorder` is:

```
Binding binding2 = new Binding("Key");
binding2.Converter = new GroupHeaderConverter();
binding2.ConverterParameter = 1;

SfBorder border = new SfBorder() { WidthRequest = 75, HeightRequest=50, Margin = 10};
border.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center;
border.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;

StackLayout score = new StackLayout() { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center};
score.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;    
Label scoreLabel = new Label() {TextColor = Color.White, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold};
scoreLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, binding2);
score.Children.Add(scoreLabel);

Binding binding3 = new Binding("Key");
binding3.Converter = new GroupHeaderConverter();
binding3.ConverterParameter = 2;

//THIS is where the binding for the SfBorder is done. 
border.SetBinding(BackgroundColorProperty, binding3);

border.Content = score;
```

This is the `GroupHeader` which gives the `Key`:

```
listView.DataSource.GroupDescriptors.Add(new GroupDescriptor()
{
    PropertyName = "CourseName",
    KeySelector = (object obj1) =>
    {
        var item = (obj1 as Data);
        return item;
        // Data is a class with different types that I need for the header
    }
});
```

This is the `Converter` for the bindings:

```
public class GroupHeaderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Data item = (Data)value;
        int c = (int)parameter;
        switch (c)
        {
            case 0:
                return item.CourseName;
            case 1:
                return item.OverallPercent;
            case 2:
                return ColorGet.ColorFromPercent((int)item.OverallPercent);
            case 3:
                return item.ClassType;
            default:
                return item.CourseName;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally, this is how I get the `Color` from the `Value`:

```
static byte interpolate(byte a, byte b, double p)
{
    return (byte)(a * (1 - p) + b * p);
}
public static Color ColorFromPercent(int v)
{
    SortedDictionary<int, Color> d = new SortedDictionary<int, Color>();
    d.Add(0, Color.Violet);
    d.Add(50, Color.OrangeRed);
    d.Add(69, Color.Yellow);
    d.Add(79, Color.Orange);
    d.Add(89, Color.Blue);
    d.Add(101, Color.Green);

    KeyValuePair<int, Color> kvp_previous = new KeyValuePair<int, Color>(-1, Color.Black);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Color> kvp in d)
    {
        if (kvp.Key > v)
        {
            double p = (v - kvp_previous.Key) / (double)(kvp.Key - kvp_previous.Key);
            Color a = kvp_previous.Value;
            Color b = kvp.Value;
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(
            interpolate(a.R, b.R, p),
            interpolate(a.G, b.G, p),
            interpolate(a.B, b.B, p));
            return c;
        }
        else if (kvp.Key == v)
        {
            return kvp.Value;
        }
    }

    return Color.Black;
}
```

P.S. If I try setting the `BindingProperty` to `SfBorder.BackgroundColorProperty` then my code throws a `NotImplementedException`, so there's something going on here that I don't understand...

Comment: I found a way to get the result that I wanted without SfBorder by replacing it with a Frame. Not really a solution, still want to know why SfBorder is giving me issues with binding

Comment: Hi, could you explain `SfBorder` is a Third Party Borfer or a Forms Control customed .

Comment: Third party border from Syncfusion [https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/border/getting-started]

Comment: Okey , do you call the `SfBorderRenderer.Init()` in the `FinishedLaunching` overridden method of the AppDelegate class after the Xamarin.Forms Framework has been initialized and before the LoadApplication is called .

Comment: Yes I do.  I have other SfBorders on the same page which work fine, but its just the background color binding that doesn't seem to work.